# Filter array of words based on array of endings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to compare two lists with Javascript. I want to output everything from WORDLIST that contains END. (should not be in the middle of the word, but the last characters)

jQuery would also work for me.

```
var WORDLIST = ['instagrampost', 'facebookpost', 'google']
var END = ['post', 'gle']

function compare() {
    var final = WORDLIST.endsWith(END, END.length);
    console.log(final);
}

// count the signs of end
// take wordlist and take end.lenght from behind
// save a word from the wordlist as result, if it contains a word from end as result
```

Comment: Use regex, something like `[a-z]*post` for matches with words ending in post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your `WORDLIST` based on whether [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) item of `END` is an ending ([`String.prototype.endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)) of a word:

```js
const WORDLIST = ['instagrampost', 'facebookposting', 'google'],
      END = ['post', 'gle'],
      
      result = WORDLIST.filter(w =>
        END.some(e => w.endsWith(e)))
        
console.log(result)
```

p.s. if you need case-insensitive match, you may do `w.toLowerCase().endsWith(e.toLowerCase())`

Comment: I agree, this seems like the most concise way of doing it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to use the script to find some nice domains. Here is an example.

var WORDLIST = ['youtube']
var END = ['.be']

output should be: found: youtube - youtu.be

Comment: @KanielOutis : Above answers your question exactly as it is stated in your original post, whereas getting `'youtu.be'` out of `['youtube']` and `['be']` seems to be totally different problem.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Yeah, I didn't exactly express myself. I'm sorry. Can you please help me anyway?

Comment: @KanielOutis : didn't see you posting another question, so prepared a [quick snippet](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/gOPeGJq?editors=0012) that solves your *real* problem as I have understood that

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution without regex, base on `indexOf` :

```js
var WORDLIST = ['instagrampost', 'facele', 'facebookpost', 'google', 'dnuiwa']
var END = ['post', 'gle']

function endsWith(wordlist, end){
  return wordlist.filter((w) => 
    end.filter((e) => w.indexOf(e) == w.length - e.length).length > 0
  );
}

console.log(endsWith(WORDLIST, END))
```